# How do we prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ is a sufficient statistic in the present context?

Tags: statistics, self-learning, hypergeometric-function

Let $n$ items be drawn in order without replacement from a shipment of $N$ items of which $N\theta$ are bad. Let $X_{i} = 1$ if the $i$-th drawn is bad and $X_{i} = 0$ otherwise. Show that $\sum X_{i}$ is sufficient for $\theta$ directly and by the factorization theorem.

The problem is I do not know which probability model should we use this context, which makes difficult to assert the given proposition. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the likelihood for $n$ observations on independent Bernoulli $X_i$'s

Comment: Hypergeometric I think?